# importing MapInfo georeferenced ratser on qgis 2.2

Tags: qgis

I do not understand why loading mapInfo shapefiles is possible in Qgis but for the georeferenced image file, is there any possible reason for this?

My major concern is that, so far georeferencing on Qgis is problematic to me (I only get to see the final result only after georefencing, which is not always well done as seen by the distortion). Given that MapInfo permits you correct your precision, I will like to georeference on MapInfo and import the file to Qgis, can anyone help me:

- Bring in this file, or
- Enlighten me more on how to better my georeferencing.